# Microsoft Graph 'mgt-people-picker' Select Members of Group

Tags: html, microsoft-graph-api, peoplepicker

In my application I want to be able to select individual members of a group in the mgt-people-picker component dropdown. I need some way of seeing the members within the group from the mgt-people-picker.

I have tried adjusting the settings to allow for selection of groups. I can find the groups easily in the mgt-people-picker but when I select them it adds the group and doesn't say the members of the group.